# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in on-finished & raw-body

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```
warning  in ./node_modules/_on-finished@2.4.1@on-finished/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'D:\project\xy2022\node_modules\_on-finished@2.4.1@on-finished'

 warning  in ./node_modules/_raw-body@2.5.1@raw-body/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'D:\project\xy2022\node_modules\_raw-body@2.5.1@raw-body'
```

Although it runs normally, it feels awkward. My colleague and I have the same version of Node, but he doesn't get this error on his machine.

Reinstall node, upgrade to the latest version, install async_hooks, and add conditional statements in the two problematic files. There might be some issues with the implementation

```
function tryRequireAsyncHooks () {
  try {
    return require('async_hooks')
    // return {}
  } catch (e) {
    return {}
  }
}
```

Both sides of the code have errors in this function. I have a feeling that I haven't used these two plugins in my project. Changing 'return require('async_hooks')' to 'return {}' resolved the error.

Note: Thank you to Estus Flask for the reminder. I have now changed the image to a code block

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . It's even unreadable. "My colleague and I have the same version of Node" - you can be certain that it's not true, so proceed from the fact that's the problem here. It won't happen if you use the recommended Node version, which is the latest 16 or 18, no odd versions. "install async_hooks" - you can't install it, it's a part of Node. If there's a package with the same name, using it to fix would be a mistake